# In dataframe, if column is not available in sheet1 then ask to and ignore case and space sensitive

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Match all column's names from sheet2 to sheet1 if anything new, ask to add in sheet3, and ignore case sensitive

In Sheet1  "fName" and in Sheet2 "fname" that should consider same (here, case sensitive) and replace name fName from **sheet2**

Same "Full Name" and in sheet2 "fullname(Ignore space and case sensitive) but that is same So, replace name fName from **sheet2**

And "Zip" is not in sheet. So, ask if you want to add zip(Y/N) if yes then in **sheet3** add
separate column

> No change in sheet1 and replace column name in sheet2 and add new columns in sheet3

**Sheet1**

```
Id fName   Address1     Full Name 
1  Parth   1, street    Parth Hirpara
2  Ujas    10, avenue   Ujas Gajera
```

**Sheet2**

```
Id fname  Zip  fullname
3  Keval  123  Keval Borad 
4  Vivek  456  Keyur Jasani
```

**Sheet2 after changing columns name**

```
Id fName  Zip  Full Name
3  Keval  123  Keval Borad 
4  Vivek  456  Keyur Jasani
```

**Final Data Sheet Columns**

> Ignore data-related things

**Sheet3**

```
Id fName   Address1    Full Name  Zip
...
...
...
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below code after loading sheet1 & sheet2 as df1 & df2 respectively...

```
df3 = df1.copy()

lst_col1 = df1.columns.to_list()
lst_col2 = df2.columns.to_list()

lst_col1_temp = [str(col).lower().replace(" ","") for col in lst_col1]
lst_col2_temp = [str(col).lower().replace(" ","") for col in lst_col2]

# Renaming columns in Sheet2 (df2)
for col1 in lst_col1:
    col1_temp = str(col1).lower().replace(" ","")
    if col1 not in lst_col2 and col1_temp in lst_col2_temp:
        lst_col2[lst_col2_temp.index(col1_temp)] = col1
        
# Adding columns in Sheet3 (df3)
for col2 in lst_col2:
    col2_temp = str(col2).lower().replace(" ","")
    if col2_temp not in lst_col1_temp:
        df3[col2] = df2[col2]
```

Hope this Helps...